# Find coefficient of Polynomial with negative roots

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Given that $x_1,x_2$ are some roots of polynomial 
$2x^4+ax^3+17x^2+11x+15=0$

If $x_1,x_2<0$ Find $a$ which is in $R$

_______________

I have tried to assume all roots are in $Q$, and get the result :

 $2x^4+11x^3+17x^2+11x+15=0$

That given two real negative roots are $-2.5$ and $-3$

 *However, how to find all solution of $a$ ?*

Comment: What happens if you form a 2nd degree polynomial = $(x - x_1)(x - x_2)?$  What then happens if you divide the original 4th degree polynomial by the 2nd degree polynomial.  You should get a new 2nd degree polynomial to analyze.  I really don't know if this approach will bear fruit, but this is the first thing that I would try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $-1\le x<0$, we have
$$2x^4+17x^2+11x+15\ge 2x^4+17x^2+4>0$$
and for $x<-1$,
$$2x^4+17x^2+11x+15=2x^4+6x^2+11x(x+1)+15>0.$$
So to have a negative root at all, we certainly need $a>0$.
As $f(0)>0$ and $f(x)\gg0$ as $x\ll 0$, we have two negative roots iff there is a point $x_0<0$ where $f(x)<0$ (strictly speaking, we might also have two negative double roots, but one can rule this possibility out quickly).
But if $f(x_0)<0$ for some $a$, then (as $x_0<0$) also $f(x_0)<0$ for all larger $a$.
We conclude that the solutions form an interval $[a_0,\infty)$ or $(a_0,\infty)$.
The boundary situation will occur when for $a=a_0$, $f$ has a *double* root at some negative $x_0$. As we do not count this as two negative roots, the solutions form the open interval $(a_0,\infty)$.

Remains to determine $a_0$.
To do so, you may use Euclid's algorithm to find the gcd of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ and see what conditions on $a$ arise for the gcd to have a negative root. At first sight, owever, this gcd computation might turn out to be somewhat lengthy.